# Как можно записать цикл из питона со стоками?

Tags: python, c++

Такой вопрос: я хотел поинтересоваться как сделать похожий цикл в python в с++.
Вот код на Python:

```
N = int(input())

csv = []
alphabet = '0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

for i in range(N):
    f = list(map(str, input().split()))
    csv += f

for i in csv:
    full_name_date = i.split(',')
    full_name = full_name_date[0] + full_name_date[1] + full_name_date[2]
    len_full_name = len(set([char for char in full_name]))
```

Вот меня интересует последний цикл. Как его можно реализовать в c++. Может кто подсказать?

Comment: ВЫ про это: `for(auto i : csv)` ?

Comment: @MBo да , а можете подсказать по поводу split в c++&

Comment: Готового, кажется, нет, можно getline из stringstream, или find+substr. А в данном случае это вообще выглядит как удаление пары запятых из строки.